# Large accumulation of log files under ~/.config/gcloud/logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We've noticed that some of our GCE instances have large accumulations of log files (1.6GB) under  `/home/deploy/.config/gcloud/logs` ("deploy" is the user under which our application processes run). It looks like one month's worth of log files are saved. A file is created every couple of seconds or so.

Each file looks like this:

```
2020-12-11 20:52:02,105 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'config', 'config_helper']
2020-12-11 20:52:02,107 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.config.config-helper] with arguments: [--format: "json", --verbosity: "none"]
2020-12-11 20:52:02,130 DEBUG    google_auth_httplib2 Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/xxx/?recursive=true
2020-12-11 20:52:02,137 DEBUG    google_auth_httplib2 Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/xxx/token
2020-12-11 20:52:02,157 INFO     root            Display format: "default json"
2020-12-11 20:52:02,159 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ {
  "configuration": {
    "active_configuration": "default",
    "properties": {
      "core": {
        "account": "xxx",
        "disable_usage_reporting": "True",
        "project": "xxx",
        "verbosity": "none"
      }
    }
  },
  "credential": {
    "access_token": "xxx",
    "id_token": "xxx",
    "token_expiry": "2020-12-11T21:36:39Z"
  },
  "sentinels": {
    "config_sentinel": "/home/deploy/.config/gcloud/config_sentinel"
  }
}
2020-12-11 20:52:02,159 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___

2020-12-11 20:52:02,160 DEBUG    root            SDK update checks are disabled.
```

(I edited out potentially sensitive information.)

I'm trying to figure out where these files come from and, more importantly, how to prevent them from being created. These files are consuming a significant amount of disk space.

These are ubuntu systems. Our applications are mostly written in Go with some Ruby and Node.js.

Comment: Where do you think they are coming from? They are log files from that particular application. Change the configuration to accumulate less logs and/or use `logrotate` to change how long they are kept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These logs are generated automatically by gcloud and cleared automatically in 30 days. You can disable it by using the command below on the cloud shell.

> gcloud config set core/disable_file_logging True

You  can learn more about the command on the [official GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set).

Comment: Thanks for that. By the way, we discovered that it's the Ruby Google Cloud SDK that runs `gcloud` in this case in order to get the project ID of the instance. We have a Ruby app running that uses Google cloud storage and that was what was ultimately causing this to happen.